# How to sort HashMap of directories depth first?

Tags: java

I created a hashmap where I store directories as keys and then their contents as values.
When I iterate over the hash map and print everything out I get

```
files/abknl/bbxudleuf/jlffhq/y/xwjj/ell/ek.java
files/abknl/bbxudleuf/jlffhq/y/xwjj/ell/nu.java
files/abknl/bbxudleuf/jlffhq/y/xwjj/ell/os.java
files/abknl/bbxudleuf/jlffhq/y/xwjj/ell/njwqdp/di.html
files/abknl/bbxudleuf/jlffhq/y/xwjj/ell/njwqdp/po.html
```

What I want to get however is

```
files/abknl/bbxudleuf/jlffhq/y/xwjj/ell/njwqdp/di.html
files/abknl/bbxudleuf/jlffhq/y/xwjj/ell/njwqdp/po.html
files/abknl/bbxudleuf/jlffhq/y/xwjj/ell/ek.java
files/abknl/bbxudleuf/jlffhq/y/xwjj/ell/nu.java
files/abknl/bbxudleuf/jlffhq/y/xwjj/ell/os.java
```

Any ideas?

To come to this I am sorting the hashmaps keys and then print the values of each key

Comment: how are you sorting the keys ?

Comment: For starters, you can't sort a HashMap. You need a SortedMap for this.

Comment: I use this:
Set<String> keys=anotherStructure.keySet();
String[] skeys=keys.toArray(new String[keys.size()]);
Arrays.sort(skeys);

Answer (score 4):

A `HashMap` is not usually sorted. You will want to use a `SortedMap`, for example [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html). This class will let you use your own [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), and thus lets you sort its contents anyway you want it. From the [`TreeMap(Comparator<? super K>)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap%28java.util.Comparator%29) constructor Javadoc:

> Constructs a new, empty tree map, ordered according to the given comparator.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) with a suitable `Comparator`, then `putAll` entries you have in your `HashMap`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to start with a `HashMap`, you can create a [`new TreeMap(myHashMap)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap%28java.util.Map%29). This will have the same mappings, but will iterate over them in sorted order.